# c# validating login with sql database

Tags: c#, sql, database, dataadapter

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EmailAddr = "";
    string Password = "";
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EPortfolioConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE [EmailAddr]=@EmailAddr AND [Password]=@Password", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddr", EmailAddr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

    SqlDataAdapter daParentLogin = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet result = new DataSet();

    conn.Open();
    daParentLogin.Fill(result, "Login");
    conn.Close();

    if (result.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid login credentials";
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("SubmitViewingRequest.aspx");
    }
}
```

the codes above doesn't validate the email address and password with the database. any email address and password entered is considered correct. can i get help? thank you!

Comment: In your code ` if (result.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid login credentials";
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("SubmitViewingRequest.aspx");` with this line of code if you have a match you are denying them access if not you are allowing them ?

Comment: Your if statement is backwards.  When count equals zero it is good and when count > 0 it is invalid.  It should be Rows.Count == 0

Comment: Instead of returning table, return the scalar value then check

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition

```
if (result.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count > 0) // For Successfully Login
{
    Response.Redirect("SubmitViewingRequest.aspx");    
}
else // For Invalid User credentials
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Invalid login credentials";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we mistakenly put if conditions in reverse order. Please change your code with if conditions replaced like this:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EmailAddr = "";
    string Password = "";
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EPortfolioConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE [EmailAddr]=@EmailAddr AND [Password]=@Password", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddr", EmailAddr);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);

    SqlDataAdapter daParentLogin = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet result = new DataSet();

    conn.Open();
    daParentLogin.Fill(result, "Login");
    conn.Close();

    if (result.Tables["Login"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
          Response.Redirect("SubmitViewingRequest.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
          lblMessage.Text = "Invalid login credentials";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hi, after making the changes, whenever i enter the correct email address and password, i am not allowed to login, showing invalid login credentials

Comment: @KerineLow please try putting some debug points and see what values are you receiving in your `EmailAddr` and `Password` and verify them in your database